# Paypal standard on contribution forms

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, paypal

Getting this error when clicking on the paypal button on the contribution form:

Payment Processor Error message
10471: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details. ReturnURL is invalid.

- I tried deleting the paypal standard as a payment processor to see what would happen but clicking the button gives the same error.

Comment: what version of civicrm? what CMS?

Comment: Using 4.6.8 on D7

Answer (score 1):

You've probably done this, but the CiviCRM wiki provides instructions on how to [set up the return URL for paypal](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Standard+and+Recurring+Contributions).

Comment: Yup. It was working before I upgraded to 4.6.8